# Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: php

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\web\xampp\htdocs\www\includes\overall\header.php:2) in C:\web\xampp\htdocs\www\register.php on line 57

```
<?php 
 if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])){
     echo 'you registered'; 
 } else {
 if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors )=== true){
 $register_data = array (
 'username' => $_POST['username'],
 'password' => $_POST['password'],
 'first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
 'last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
 'email' => $_POST['email']
 );
 register_user($register_data);
 header('location: register.php?success');
exit();
 } else if(empty($errors)===false){
 echo output_errors($errors);
 }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: [Решение проблемы "Cannot add header information - headers already sent"](http://www.phpfaq.ru/headers)

Answer (score 0):

До header не должно быть ни одного echo, print и т. д.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=endscreen&NR=1&v=5A50qmC7wFo
а здесь есть и ничего работает отлично

Comment: Возможно у вас на сервере включен высокий уровень ошибок php. Поэтому выходит эта ошибка.  Вы можете использовать переадресацию на JavaScript: <script>
 document.location.href='index.php'; </script>. Вместо index.php нужно поставить адрес страницы, на которую пользователь должен переадресовываться.
Пользователь все равно не заметит, на чем построена переадресация.